# Is there an "explicit" construction of the complex plane in ZFC?

Tags: complex-numbers, set-theory

I came over an interetsing claim in a book, which states that $\mathbb{C} := \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}$. Traditionally, we say that the complex plane is $\mathbb{R} \times \mathrm{Im}$, where $\mathrm{Im} = \{ ai : a \in \mathbb{R}, i = \sqrt{-1} \}$. I see why you could imagine the complex plane as $\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}$, since the notation for complex numbers $a + bi$ (where $a,b \in\mathbb{R}$) is just a way to express a vector in the complex plane, which can also be written as $(a,b)$ (correct me if I'm wrong here, it's summer holidays and I'm a bit rusty on this).

This got me thinking whether someone took a more difficult (i.e. an *explicit*) approach and actually defined the set $\mathrm{Im}$ and then took the Cartesian product of it and $\mathbb{R}$ to get $\mathbb{C}$. The particular thing which interests me here is how one defines $i$ in ZFC in this approach.

Comment: As a set, you can just define $\mathbb{C}$ to be $\mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}$, there is nothing complicated set-theoretically about it. (So $i$ is simply the element $(0,1)$ from $\mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}$.) You then proceed to give it some algebraic structure (namely that of a field) by defining addition and multiplication the way you're used to it from $\mathbb{C}$.

Comment: Your "Traditionally..." may well be how people think of it but it cannot possibly be used as the official definition! Because $ia$ is undefined. Much simpler just to say $\mathbb C=\mathbb R^2$ (which _is_ the absolutely standard, traditional definition.)

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich Well, I might correct my question by adding that by "traditionally" I mean approximately how we defined the complex plane in high school. :D

Comment: @GregorPerčič Ahi ahi ahi :-) you have used in MathJaX `\mathrm{Im}` instead of `operatorname{Im}`. +1 for the question and regards as user of TeX.SE.

Answer (score 5):

In fact it would be better to define $\mathbb C$ as a field over $\mathbb R \times \mathbb R$ endowed with $+$ and $\cdot $ operations.

Those operations are maps with usual properties defining $\mathbb C$. For example
$$(a,b) \cdot (c,d) = (ac-bd,ad+bc).$$
They can therefore be defined in ZFC.

Then $i$ is just the element $(0,1)$ and it satisfies the equality $i \cdot i =(-1,0)$.

Comment: I've thought about defining $i$ as $(1,0)$, but a worry came up. When we construct the real plane $\mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}$, the real numbers, meaning the elements of the set $\mathbb{R}$, are gone, they don't exist in the set $\mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}$. When we unaccuratly speak of the "real numbers" in the real plane, we really mean the ordered pairs of the form $\{ (a,0) : a \in \mathbb{R} \}$. Continued in the next comment...

Comment: So while I recognise that we can think of $i$ as $(1,0)$, it seems weird that we have a whole set for $x$ axis and that the elements of $y$ axis do not have such a set of their own, but are constructed from the elements of $x$ axis.

Comment: @GregorPerčič You are right that $\mathbb{R}$ will not be a true subset of $\mathbb{C}$ in this construction, but this is no problem as you already identified the correct _embedding_. This occurs a lot in mathematics, where we would consider something a subset of something else, but what really happens is that there is some translation necessary. Another example would be $\mathbb{N}$ and $\mathbb{Z}$. In most standard constructions we do not literally have $\mathbb{N} \subseteq \mathbb{Z}$, but there will always be an obvious embedding that preserves all relevant properties.